# How to format a long json text from Wordpress in Android

Tags: java, android, json, string, wordpress

I have asked this question before, but I did not get a helpful answer.

I get a long json text in my Android app from Wordpress and I want to format it to have paragraph. As the text has bullets like 1,2,3, - I need the text to display in the below format:

1........

2.......

3.......

This is how I am getting it in json:

```
public class Didyouknow extends SherlockListActivity {

private ActionBarMenu abm;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_QUERY = "posts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";


 // contacts JSONArray
 JSONArray query = null;

 // Hashmap for ListView
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> queryList;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_upcoming);

  ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
  actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  abm = new ActionBarMenu(Didyouknow.this);

  if (com.cepfmobileapp.org.service.InternetStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)) {

   // Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,"You are online!!!!",8000).show();
   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You are online",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetQuery().execute();

   } else {
     AlertDialog NetAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Didyouknow.this).create();
   NetAlert.setMessage("No Internet Connection Found!");
        NetAlert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            } });
        NetAlert.show();
   }

  queryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  ListView lv = getListView();

  // Listview on item click listener
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem


        // Starting single contact activity
        /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleContactActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
        in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
        in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
        startActivity(in);*/

     }
   });

  }

   private String parseHtml(String html){
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  return doc.text();
  }


  private class GetQuery extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Showing progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Didyouknow.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            query = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_QUERY);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = query.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
                //String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                //String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                contact.put(TAG_CONTENT, parseHtml(content));
                //contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                // adding contact to contact list
                queryList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
  }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: as your response text is in html, why you are not showing the html directly?

Comment: could you post the JSON you want to parse? And also, where is the parsed string supposed to be showed?

Comment: @JoakimPalmkvist, this is the link to the JSON http://pastebin.com/87DCfxvN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JSON you are looking at is in hmtl you can probably display it in a html page.

If you want to parse the String using Java here is a rough sketch of how you can do it:

update:
Your code:

```
JSONObject c = query.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String content = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);
```

The String content now holds the content string from the JSONObject.

```
String[] split = content.split("<p>2");
```

Now you have an array of Strings,

```
split1[0] = "<p>1)...."
split1[1] = ")content of p2 and p3 and so forth..."
```

So you need the substring from [0] that will remove the `"<p>1"`
so

```
paragraph1 = split[0].substring(3);
```

then you will have to split split[1] to get paragraph 2 and the rest

```
String[] split2 = split[1].split("<p>3");
String paragraph2 = split2[0];
```

keep doing this to get all the paragraphs you need.
Its easier if you print out each String after every split, then you will get a better grip of whats going on.

Comment: am trying it but, didnt get it, please can you kindly help answer this using my code, as i am a rookie in this